# How to retrieve name of Array which is stored in wpf list

Tags: wpf

In my one Application I have declared one List

```
public List<double[]> pane1 = new List<double[]>();
```

// Below code is to add some double arrays in this list

```
pane1.Add(imp);

pane1.Add(normal);

pane1.Add(useless);
```

// Below code is retrieving of values from this list

```
            foreach (double[] pan in pane1)
            {
                int diffx = ds.data.Length - pan.Length;
                int pointx = ptx - diffx;

                if (pointx < 0)
                    pointx = 0;


                double tip = pan[pointx];
                tt = tt.Append("\n");
                //tt = tt.Append(pan.ToString());
                tt = tt.Append("\t");
                tt = tt.Append(Math.Round(tip, 2));


            }
```

***Question : I am able to retrieve data of these arrays successfully , but I also want to retrieve name of arrays , is it possible ?***

Comment: What do you mean "name of arrays"?

Comment: name of variable which points to array at that time when i stored them into list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. The "name" that you seem to be looking for is not "the name of the array"; it is just a name of a variable that happens to point to the array.

There could be several variables pointing to that very same array at a time. Case in point, would you expect the line you have commented out in your code to write `pan`? After all, that is the name of *a* variable that points to the current array.

Comment: i never expected that commented line to execute, motive was just to show that , in this line i intend to store name of that array variable  .

Comment: Any suggestion how can i implement my requirement , Nothing is impossible in programming , if not this way then may be some other way around , can u give me any idea how can i store name of these array variables.

Comment: @NidhiSharma: Well, what do you think *is* the name of the array variable in that line? Is it always `pan`? Or is it either of `imp`, `normal` or `useless`? I'm trying to show why there is no such thing as a name of a given array, because there can be any number of variables pointing to that array at any given time.

Comment: @NidhiSharma: If you are looking to store a name *along* with an array, just define a struct or a class that contains two fields; an array and a string. Make your `pane1` list contain instances of that type rather than just arrays.

Comment: thanks Mapper you gave me idea which i can work upon , Although jon gave solution , but i have never used dictionary nor i am able to get resources from google to move ahead , so i am implementing ur idea

Answer (score 0):

The names of the variables in source code are lost when the program is compiled, so you cannot ever do this. What you can do is use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of a `List`:

```
public Dictionary<string, double[]> pane1 = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();

pane1["imp"] = imp;
pane1["normal"] = normal;
pane1["useless"] = useless;
```

You can then both iterate over `pane1.Values` to get the arrays without paying attention to the keys (names), or iterate over `pane1` to get name/array pairs, or pull out an array by name with

```
var imp = pane1["imp"];
```

Comment: I never used dictionary before can you tell me please, how to retrieve values and these names

Comment: @NidhiSharma: It's all in the documentation; you will also find lots of information by googling. `Dictionary` is a very popular class.

Comment: last question , are u aware that imp , normal and useless were variable names which points to array which may have length of 1000  ,  pane1["imp"] = imp ; You mean to say i would be able to retrieve data

Comment: @NidhiSharma: Of course you would. `double d = pane1["imp"][500]`

Comment: While it is possible to implement this as described, I'm not convinced it is a good solution because essentially, we are doing a lookup for a key based on its value (i.e. inverse to what dictionary is meant to do). It's ok if this is merely about an iteration over all values, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double[]> pane1 = new List<double[]>();
            Check(() => pane1);
        }

        static void Check<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
        {
            var body = ((MemberExpression)expr.Body);
            Console.WriteLine("Name is: {0}", body.Member.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

> Variable name is: pane1

Comment: i guess i am not able to explain question well , so please close my question by voting it down